# Pop-up effect or Scaling effect with SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I've created several shapes in SVG and added an effect that changes the shapes color when hovered over.

But how can I make the shapes "pop up" slightly when hovered over?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, even if that answer is your own.  It will help anyone who sees this question in the future identify a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to do what I wanted by adding

```
target.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', "translate(0 0)");
```

as such:

```
function unselectedColour(evt) {
var target = evt.target;
target.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'white');
target.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', "translate(0 0)");

}

function selectedColourBuilding(evt) {
var target = evt.target;
target.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'purple');
target.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', "translate(-3 -3)");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the [transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#SVGGlobalTransformAttribute) of each element. Probably something like this:

```
function onEnter (e) {
    e.target.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(2,2)');
}

function onLeave (e) {
    e.target.removeAttribute('transform');
}
```

But in fact you do not need to take the long slow way using the attributes, instead you can use the `transform` interface of SVG elements. The documentation therefore is on the page linked above, too. But dealing with this might be a bit »unintuitive« the first time, since each element has a `transform list` with several `transform items`.

I think it would be a good Idea to dive in the svg transform interface (and affine transformations in general), since it is very powerful, but it requires a »learning curve« before you are ready to use it.

If you want to short circuit this you can also use a helper framework like: [svg.js](http://www.svgjs.com/), [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/) or [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) which all have common methods to help you dealing with thing like that.

**EDIT**

The functions above are just examples for one could do it. The `onEnter` and `onLeave` methods should be called only if the mouse enters the svg element or when it leaves. So you could add a `mousemove` listener and check if the target is one of your desired elements:

```
var firstElement = document.getElementById('<yourelementsid>'); 
    isOverFirstElement = false;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (e.target === firstElement && isOverFirstElement == false) {
        isOverFirstElement = true;
        onEnter(e);
    } else if (e.target !== firstElement && isOverFirstElement == true) {
        isOverFirstElement = false;
        onLeave(e);
    }
}, false);
```

With code like that you can detect a mouse enter or leave and react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've added this 

`function onEnter (mySquare) {
    mySquare.target.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(2,2)');
}

function onLeave (mySquare) {
    mySquare.target.removeAttribute('transform');
}`

But it does nothing. I'm doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

To make the 'pop out' stable, keeping it at it's current position when scaling, you can compute the center of its bounding box then translate the element's center to the origin, scale it, then translate back to its current location

e.g.

```
function onEnter(evt)
{
    var target=evt.target
    var bb=target.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    var cx=bbx+.5*bbw
    var cy=bby+.5*bbh
    target.setAttribute("transform","translate("+(cx)+" "+(cy)+")scale(1.2 1.2)translate("+(-cx)+" "+(-cy)+")")
}
function onExit(evt)
{
    var target=evt.target
    target.removeAttribute("transform")
```

}